# Why is famas the default counter-terrorist auto-buy rifle even with plenty of money?

Tags: counter-strike-2

Using F3 in the buy zone at the start of the round buys a weapon automatically, based on the amount of money available.

When playing terrorist, the auto-buy rifle is the AK-47, as long as enough money is available. I expected the M4A1-S / M4A4 to be the default for counter-terrorists, but the weapon I get, even with $5000 is the famas. Why is this? Can I change the auto-buy settings?

Comment: You tagged your question with both the CSGO and CS2 tags. Are you asking about both games or only CS2?

Comment: CSGO tag removed, I wasn't sure how it used to work before version 2 released, but it appears to have changed recently.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A quick search on the internet shows that more people are experiencing this. they assume it has to do with the recent update not updating the autobuy file correctly.

Following the commandlines of Counter Strike 2:
https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/List_of_Counter-Strike_2_console_commands_and_variables

The default should be:
`cl_autobuy vesthelm vest m4a1 ak47 famas galilar mp7 nova defuser`. If you paste this command in the command terminal it should fix the autobuy function. The command should be permanent because it changes your autobuy file.

It will buy in this order till a slot is filled and then skip all 'later' option of filled slots. You can also play around with it in this way changing it to your preferred tools of the trade.